# How to check a windows process status? C++, WinApi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

How can I check a windows process status if it's "running" or "suspended" ?
GetExitCodeProcess function returns STILL_ACTIVE value but it's not enough. 
Are there any function to get the processs status?

Comment: AFAIK you can't suspend a process, only a thread.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious NtSuspendProcess -- Undocumented though so I guess you are correct.

Comment: @Brandon Which is undocumented and not officially supported so it really shouldn't be relied on

Comment: I will periodically spot a suspended process in Process Explorer, so it can be done. That said Mark Russinovich has access to a wee bit more information than I do. [Literally wrote the book on it](http://www.amazon.ca/Windows-Internals-Part-2-6th/dp/0735665877/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1440709405&sr=1-4).

Comment: Presumably NtSuspendProcess works by suspending all the threads in the process (perhaps atomically?) so you could determine whether a process has been suspended by enumerating the threads.  If all the threads are suspended, the process is suspended.